# My JavaScript code throws a SyntaxError (Unexpected token <)

Tags: backbone.js

any one help me to find our the issue, what is going on with my code..

i am getting the error as :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

my code is here :

```
$(function() {

    var userDetails=[
        {firstName:'Lakshmi', lastName:'Narayanan',age:32},
        {firstName:'Harish', lastName:'Manickam',age:28},
        {firstName:'Madan', lastName:'Gopal',age:27}
    ]

    var userModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults:{
            firstName:"",
            lastName:"",
            age:""
        }
    });

    var userList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model:userModel
    });

    var userView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName:"tr",
        className:"userList",
        template: $("#listTempalate").html(),
        render:function(){
            var temp = _.template(this.template);
            this.$el.html(temp(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });

    var usersView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el:"tbody",
        initialize:function(){
            this.collection = new userList(userDetails);
            this.render();
        },
        render:function(){
            var that = this;
            _.each(this.collection.models, function(item){
                that.$el.append(new userView({model:item}).render().el);
            })
        }
    });

    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes:{
            '' : 'home'
        }
    });

    var router = new Router();
    router.on('route:home', function(){
        var defaultUser = new usersView();
    })

    Backbone.history.start();

});
```

my HTML :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,Chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
    <title>User Manager</title>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>User Manager</h1>
        <hr>
        <div class="page">
            <table class="table striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="insertRows">

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script id="listTempalate" type="text/template">
        <td><%= firstName %></td>
        <td><%= lastName %></td>
        <td><%= age %></td>
        <td><%= <a hre="#/edit/<%= user.id %>" class="btn">Edit</a></td>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.0.0/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/userManager.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Seriously i unable to find my issue here to fix it. as well any one suggest me to find the issue for backbone.js online..

so let me keep check my code..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Consider changing the title from "How to solve this issue" to something that describes the problem.

Comment: How about the in your HTML are you including some inline `script` tags?

Comment: Make sure that your indent is right, the debugger sometimes decides to come up with some non-sense-making errors if you're not indenting it equally everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure it is to do with this line in your HTML

```
<td><%= <a hre="#/edit/<%= user.id %>" class="btn">Edit</a></td>
```

You open the `<%=` and then open it again `/edit/<%=` which I think is causing the problem. Even if opening it twice is allowed, you haven't added a final `%>` to the line.

Play around with that and let us know how it goes.

**EDIT**

Try this instead

```
<td> <a href="#/edit/<%= user.id %>" class="btn">Edit</a></td>
```

You shouldn't need to wrap the entire thing in the `<%` and `%>` tags, just the part you want to output.

Comment: I converted to like this: <td><%= <a hre="#/edit/<%= user.id %>" class="btn">Edit</a> %></td> but no luck..

Comment: Updated answer after looking at a few other examples of the templating online. Give that a shot.

Comment: Based on your Javascript code, it seems to be simply because `user` really _isn't_ defined and your userModel doesn't have a property ID. Do you see how your other sections of the template use the straight property value? eg. `firstName` vs `user.firstName`

Comment: yes, you are correct, but i fixed that issue... here is my jsfiddle can you have a look...http://jsfiddle.net/kAWfW/

Comment: Thanks for the jsFiddle, made it a lot easier to work out. I have done an update to it here: http://jsfiddle.net/kAWfW/1/

What your code was doing was creating a new tbody for insertRows when you rendered the view. After looking at some examples online, if you pass a jQuery element in an object as "el" to `usersview` it will use that when it inserts.

Minor update to the HTML as well so it doesn't double up on "tr" elements.